# Using DATEADD with certain condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to use the dateadd function to add a number of days found in one column to a certain timestamp found in another column.

```
select number_id,
DATEADD('days',NUM_DAY, MY_DATETIME) as LAST_DATETIME
FROM TBL1
GROUP BY 1
```

However, for each number_id, I might have more than one "num_day". For each number_id, I only want have one record, and the NUM_DAY should select the LAST num_day that was inserted based on last **added_timestap**.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

FIRST_VALUE/[LAST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value.html) is your friend here:

```
SELECT number_id,
    LAST_VALUE(num_day) OVER (PARTITION BY number_id ORDER BY added_timestap) AS last_num_day,
    DATEADD('days',last_num_day, my_datedtime) AS last_datetime
FROM table
```

But that will get the last value all rows past/future of this row, which might be what you want, but if you want between all past row and this row you will want this:

```
SELECT number_id,
    LAST_VALUE(num_day) OVER (PARTITION BY number_id ORDER BY added_timestap RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS last_num_day,
    DATEADD('days',last_num_day, my_datedtime) AS last_datetime
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "last-edit"-timestamp to the Table "TBL1"

| num_day | last_edit | number_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 01.12.2021 10:11:16.0 | 01 |
| 13 | 01.12.2021 11:11:16.0 | 01 |

... and get the result with a sub-select.

```
SELECT
  number_id,
  DATEADD('days',NUM_DAY, MY_DATETIME) as LAST_DATETIME
FROM TBL1
WHERE 
  number_id = '01' 
  AND last_edit in (
    SELECT
     max(last_edit)
    FROM 
      TBL1
    WHERE
      number_id = '01'
);
```